# Load and concatenate numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have several numpy arrays, and I want to read them and concatenate them all together:

For loading the files I did the following:

```
import numpy as np
AVERAGE_files = glob.glob('*AVERAGE*')
for AV in AVERAGE_files:
    x = np.load(AV)
```

Now for the concatenation I know that I have to use the `np.concatenate` function, but I don't know how to start the concatenation. Do I have to declare a `np.zeros` array outside the cycle?

Comment: FYI, usually numpy is imported as np, not as num

Comment: What's the shape of these arrays?

Comment: @hpaulj the shape is (1,)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely just something like this?

```
import numpy as np

new = np.array([])

for AV in AVERAGE_files:
   x = np.load(AV) # I assume num in your example is an alias for numpy?
   new = np.concatenate([new,x])
```

Comment: Just a little correction:                                                                             new= np.concatenate([new,x])                                                                      Thanks. I'm new at python scripting

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the individual arrays loaded as `x1, x2, x3`, you can use

```
x = numpy.vstack((x1, x2, x3))
```

but it's probably more efficient to use something like @areuexperienced's concatenation technique since you don't keep the individual `x1`s.

Comment: In timings that I've done in the past, one concatenation on the whole list is faster.  The incremental approach will not save memory.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays cannot be appended to, only copied. Thus `np.concatenate` results in a *new* array which is identical to the old except the extra values. Constructing an array by successive concatenation, while certainly possible, is not an efficient approach.

If the size of the files is known you are almost certainly better off allocating an array with `np.zeros` out of cycle, as you suggest:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.zeros([size])
for i in range(0,len(AVERAGE_files)):
    with open(AVERAGE_files[i]) as f: #assuming AV are strings?
       array[i] = map(float,f)
```

Alternatively you can build a list (which can be appended to efficiently) and then convert it to an array at the end:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.asarray([map(float,open(AV)) for AV in AVERAGE_files])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite fast and very pythonic compared to the other answers

```
import numpy as np
AVERAGE_files = glob.glob('*AVERAGE*')
x_averages = np.concatenate([np.load(average_file) for average_file in AVERAGE_files], dtype=float)
```